# How to change the color of an item(ScaleDrawable) of an existing layer-list programatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar, layer-list

I have an existing layer-list used to customize a ProgressBar which looks like this:

**style_progress_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="#F6F3F1" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="#DE0012"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="#DE0012"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This layer-list is used to override a ProgressBar's progressDrawable attribute and works like a charm.

Now, I want to use the same backbone but I'd like to change the color of the second and third item programmatically, because the progress color should change in a lot of situations and creating tons of xml files is something I wouldn't do and wouldn't even be a good idea.

I managed to read the above file and read it's second and third item but I can't find a proper solution to change the color of these 2. Except the color issue, everything works as expected.

```
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style_progress_bar);
int color = getResources().getColor(colorId); // This is the ID of the new color. I use it elsewhere so this should be 100% good

layers.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
layers.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

// I even called invalidate(); after all this. Nothing changed
```

I feel like I'm really close to wrap this up but I got stuck.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I really got ahead of myself here, sorry.

Digging deeper I realized I can read the needed 2 drawable as ScaleDrawable objects because this is how they are set in the xml file, as scale.

Each of these scale items have their own drawables set:

```
<scale 
    android:drawable="#DE0012" 
    android:scaleWidth="100%" />
```

So I realized, those could be read somehow as well. And yes they can be read as ColorDrawable objects. And at the point I had my 2 ColorDrawable objects, I was able to simply set a color to these.
Here is my final code to do everything:

```
private Drawable createDrawable(int colorId) {
    LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable. style_progress_bar);
    int color = getResources().getColor(colorId);
    try {
        ScaleDrawable first = (ScaleDrawable) layers.getDrawable(1);
        ScaleDrawable second = (ScaleDrawable) layers.getDrawable(2);
        ColorDrawable secondaryColor = (ColorDrawable) first.getDrawable();
        secondaryColor.setColor(color);
        ColorDrawable primaryColor = (ColorDrawable) second.getDrawable();
        primaryColor.setColor(color);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return layers;
}
```

And after this, I can simply call the above method and have my colors changed dynamically.

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(createDrawable(colorId));
```

Thanks, and sorry for this, but I think I'll leave the question in case somebody else gets stuck on this exceptional case when you need to use ScaleDrawable.

Be aware that using something else than *scale* in your xml *layer-list*'s item, would fully color the progressView and you wouldn't get the desired result, like having a a different background color and another color for the actual progress.